# Does CakePHP 2.x fix performance issues with deep nested containable queries

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I'm working on a legacy CakePHP app built on the 1.3.x branch, which makes heavy use of the Containable behavior and specifically deep nested contains.

It has become apparent that this is a massive performance issue due to the way CakePHP framework handles the queries underneath deep contains.  In one request we have over 10K queries followed by Cake merging the data together into an array.

Can anyone confirm if these issues are fixed in the Cake 2.x branch and by upgrading the framework we could make headway on performance issues.

Due to time constraints, we can currently either upgrade or tackle re-writing parts of the system to not use Containable, but not both.

I would prefer to upgrade as there are other benefits to be had, but I need to be sure that our performance issues will be tackled.

Example of deep nested contain

```
$this->Event->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => $conditions,
        'contain' => array(
            'SessionDay' => array(
                    'Activity' => array(
                     'TimeSlot' => array(
                        'TimeSlotBooking',
                            'order' => array('slot_time' => 'asc')
                    )
                    )
            ),
            'Activity' => array(
                'TimeSlot' => array(
                    'TimeSlotBooking',
                    'order' => array('slot_time' => 'asc')
                )
            ),
            'Interview' => array(
                'InterviewBooking',
                'order' => array('interview_time' => 'asc')
            ),
            'EventCode'
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using very deep nested containable queries on a project with Cake 2.x and they work well.

It still produces multiple queries and in some cases instead of doing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x IN (1,2,3)
```

it will do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = (1)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = (2)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = (3)
```

So you can end up with a lot of queries. At the end of the day it's going to depend on how many rows you actually need to retrieve from all your tables.

I'd suggest installing another Cake 2 project along side using the same database. Just quickly copy over your models and run your biggest query, then look at the difference in the query debug output for any differences.

Comment: I doubt you will see any difference in the queries, most improvements come from dropping php4 support, while the DBO layer has remained mostly the same.

Comment: @dogmatic69 this is not entirely true. Cake >= 2 implements the [PSR-0](https://gist.github.com/1234504) standard, this does have a positive performance hit on code execution. Evad you can also use Ad Hoc joins with "manual" queryes in order to gain performance. Cake will first go through these containable definitions, then build the queryes and then execute them. So maybe manual joins could also be the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm going to try Jleagle's suggestion during down time at Xmas (seeing as I would love to update our core) but for actual work reasons our first priority will be replacing the worst offenders with ad-hoc joins. As mentioned, I need to be sure management see improvements :)